# How to conditionally apply an onClick listener depending on state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I have something like this,

```
const Component = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useReducer(open => !open, false)

  const doSomething = () => console.log('did something')

  return <div onClick={open && doSomething}></div>
}
```

Then it would throw a warning,

```
Expected onClick listener to be a function, instead got 'false'
```

I know that I can do something like,

```
<div onClick={open ? () => doSomething : null}></div>
```

or

```
<div onClick={() => open ? doSomething() : null}></div>
```

But I'm wondering if there is a way to approach it as in the first example? Or is a ternary operator the only way to do this here?

Comment: Did you consider checking `open` inside the `doSomething()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you handle conditions in handler itself?

Like:

```
const Component = {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useReducer(open => !open, false)

  const doSomething = useCallback(() => {
    if (!open) {
       return;
    }
    console.log('do something');
  }, []);

  return <div onClick={doSomething}></div>
}
```

Consider using `useCallback` so that you can avoid redefining `doSomething` whenever there is state update.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest checking for `open` inside doSomething.

```
const doSomething = () => {
  if (!open) return;
  // actually do something
}
```

That way you can completely get rid of the ternary statement and your onClick is dependent on doSomething only, as opposed to both open and doSomething.

Answer (score 0):

Put your flag check into the function e.g.

```
const doSomething = () => open && console.log('did something');
return <div onClick={doSomething}></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the onClick property requires a function to work, the best you can do that still resembles the original sintax would be something like this:

```
const Component = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useReducer(open => !open, false)

  const doSomething = () => console.log('did something')

  return <div onClick={() => (open && doSomething())}></div>
}
```